# What is the difference between delay and difference properties of z-transform?

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

I'm working on a discrete updating algorithm as follows:

$x[n+1]=Kx[n]$
Here $K$ is a constant.

The continuous counterpart of this algorithm translates to:

$\dot{x(t)}=Kx(t)$

While the Laplace transform of the continuous one is quite obvious, I'm struggling to find the z-transform of the discrete one. Do I use the delay property? or the first difference property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by Laplace transform
$$\dot{x(t)}=Kx(t)$$
becomes
$$sX(s)=KX(s)$$
The by analogy, using the z-transform
$$x[n+1]=Kx[n]$$
becomes
$$zX(z)=KX(z)$$
This is simply using the time delay property

Answer (score 0):

Some complements to the accepted answer.

**Derivative under Discrete and Continuous Time**

The *Derivative System* under *Continuous Time* $t$:
$$
y(t)=k\dot x(t)
$$

Can be approximated under several ways, once of them is the *Forward Euler Approximation*, with a sample time $dt$, under *Discrete Time* $t$
$$
y[t]=k\frac1{dt}(x[t+1]-x[t])
$$

**Derivative Laplace and Z-Transform**

As you can find under any table, or under some simple calculation, the Laplace Transform (with $x(0)=0$) for the Continuous Time* expression is:
$$
Y(s)=ksX(s)
$$
While the z-Transform for the *Discrete Time* expression is
$$
Y(z)=k{(z-1) \over dt}Z(z)
$$

**Continuous vs Discrete Time Approximation**

While the previous can be seen obvious, the non so obvious fact, is in this way you have made an [approximate](https://ocw.aprende.org/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-003-signals-and-systems-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_003F11_lec07.pdf) for the 's' variable from continuous space in terms of the 'z' variable in discrete time.
This is the Forward Euler Approximation:
$$
s \approx {z-1 \over dt}
$$
This is the Reverse Euler Approximation:
$$
s \approx {1\over dt}{z-1 \over z}
$$
And this is the Trapezoidal Approximation:
$$
s \approx {2\over dt}{z-1 \over z+1}
$$
Among others.

**Exact Z vs S Variable Change**

So, you are approximating the following **known, exact variable change**, (but for some reason is not so known), for $dt \to 0$, which you can readily check by inspecting the formula and i.e. the fact that $e^x \approx x+1$ for $x \to 0$. Of course, you are not going to use this in Discrete Time, since then there would not be any reason to create the Z-Transform framework at all:
$$
z=e^{sdt}
$$